# object, Object displaying in nested *ngFor in angular with dynamic headers

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I want to display a list of object which have dynamic number of keys in angular inside a table, but it always shows [object,Object] in the output, I have tried multiple options from stack overflow but none of them worked. My data looks like this.

```
ComparableCompaniesRatiosData = [{2008: 151260,2009: 121886,2010: 122542,2011: 198630,2012: 450840,2013: 537416,2014: 673084,ComparableParty: "CompanyName",FYE: "31-12"},{2008: 151260,2009: 121886,2010: 122542,2011: 198630,2012: 450840,2013: 537416,2014: 673084,ComparableParty: "companyName",FYE: "31-12"}]
//these table headers are dynamic
ComparablePartyHeadersTrimmed = ["ComparableParty", "FYE", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014"]
```

I have tried the following to display the list:

1 : I tried with classic for loop.

```
  <tbody>    
    <ng-container *ngIf="showRatiosData">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(ComparableCompaniesRatiosData.length); let item = index"  data-toggle="modal">
        <td *ngFor="let value of [].constructor(ComparablePartyHeadersTrimmed.length); let i = index"  >
          <span>{{ComparableCompaniesRatiosData[item][i]}}</span>
        </td>   
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
```

2 : with KeyValue Pipe.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showRatiosData">
  <tr  *ngFor="let row of ComparableCompaniesRatiosData" data-toggle="modal">
    <td *ngFor="let item of row | keyvalue">
      <span>{{item.value}}</span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

3 : And with simple angular *ngFor as well.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="showRatiosData">
    <tr *ngFor="let item of ComparableCompaniesRatiosData"   data-toggle="modal">
        <td *ngFor="let row of ComparablePartyHeadersTrimmed"  >
          <span>{{item[row]}}</span>
        </td> 
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've added a new method getValue() which takes the item and property name and returns the value.

```
  getValue(item, property): any {
    return item[property];
  }
```

Then in the HTML, first loop through the data, then through the headers, and call the getValue() with the row and the header name.

```
<table class="table" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let header of ComparablePartyHeadersTrimmed" >{{header}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of ComparableCompaniesRatiosData">
        <td *ngFor="let property of ComparablePartyHeadersTrimmed" >
      {{getValue(item,property)}}
    </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-table-columns-example